# convert month-day-year into day-month-year using javascript

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm trying to convert a `MM/DD/YYYY` date to a long date. So for example, `02/16/2020` would convert to something like `16/02/2020`.

Is there a way to make this date conversion accurately?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: alert(moment(startdate).format('dd/MM/YYYY')); i tired like this

Comment: What about `moment(startdate, "MM/DD/YYYY").format('DD/MM/YYYY');`?

Comment: @Jacky, Try this approach https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/XWbKQBe

Comment: invalid date showing alon eitan

Comment: @Jacky I tried `const date = "02/16/2020"; alert(moment(date, "MM/DD/YYYY").format('DD/MM/YYYY'));` and it did work - See [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y95oc2xe/1/)

Comment: yes working it is working when i put " "

Comment: i have another doubt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the original format of the time, and then convert it to a new format.

```js
const date = "02/16/2020";
alert(moment(date, "MM/DD/YYYY").format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `moment` for date formatting:

Sample Code:

```
moment('02/16/2020').format('16/02/2020');
```

You can play with date by `moment.js`. It is very useful tool for `javascript` developer.

[Momemet Js Document](https://momentjs.com/docs/)

For dynamic value:

```
moment(yourDate, 'MM/DD/YYYY').format('DD/MM/YYYY');
```

Here, `yourDate` is your dynamic value date.

Comment: hello what is this how i change like the date is dynamic value for eg i gave this date

Comment: hello, @Jacky I edited my answer for dynamic value. Please read it.

Comment: Do you include moment.js, in your project? Please, read moment.js documentaion. How to integrate and how to use?

Comment: i have another doubt can i asked

Comment: if i assign the date = 02/16/2020 for that result i got the answer.But when i assign it like var date = $('#startdate").html(); now how i change it

Comment: @Jacky in this case, you should write this code by this way like this,
var date = new Date($('#date-input').val()); 
moment(date).format('DD/MM/YYYY');

Comment: i have tired in this way itself var date = $('#startdate").html(); and i got correct result

Answer (score 1):

check this. its work.

```js
function formatDate(date) {
    var d = new Date(date),
        month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
        day = '' + d.getDate(),
        year = d.getFullYear();

    if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
    if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;

    return [day,month,year].join('/');
}
document.getElementById('res').innerHTML =  formatDate('02/16/2020') ;
```

```html
<div id="res">res</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

2 || 1 liners ?

```js
var src = '02/16/2020'
var a = src.split('/');
console.log(a.concat(a.splice(0, 2)).join('/'));
console.log(src.replace(/(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)/, '$3/$1/$2'));
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want a conversion just between the exact formats you have mentioned:

```js
function dfConvert(f) {
  var farr = f.split("/");
  return `${farr[1]}/${farr[0]}/${farr[2]}`;
}

var input = "02/16/2020";
console.log(`input: ${input}`)
console.log(`output: ${dfConvert(input)}`);
```

2. If you want the actual date object and from that you want your mentioned format for some reason:

```js
function toDate(f) {
  var farr = f.split("/");
  return new Date(parseInt(farr[2]), parseInt(farr[0])-1, parseInt(farr[1]))
}

function dfConvert(f) {
  var d = toDate(f)
  var day = d.getDate()
  var month = (d.getMonth() + 1)
  var year = d.getFullYear()
  return `${((day.toString().length <= 1) ? "0": "")}${day}/${((month.toString().length <= 1) ? "0": "")}${month}/${year}`
}

var input = "02/16/2020"
console.log(`input: ${input}`)
console.log(`output: ${dfConvert(input)}`)
```

Hope it helps